# Delphi 2010 Error Insight incorrectly flags "Undeclared Identifier"

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

In D2010, Error Insight is incorrectly underlining in red types like "TOpenDialog" (even though my unit and project's uses both include Dialogs).

Also, in my method TMyFrame.Foo, it fails the same way by flagging  a reference to a VCL component in my TMyFrame -- *even though Foo and the component are both part of TMyFrame*.

SO suggested I read several threads on this subject. One mentions a D2009 fix for this. Is there a D2010 fix?

Other postings have suggested that Error Insight yields too many false alarms and should just be turned off.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Delphi 2010 with all its updates, and latest version of [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=246), I usually don't have such a problem in Delphi 2010.

I had it a few times, which was fixed by restarting the IDE.